# Unable to determine error messages while implementing passport.js local-signup

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

I'm adapting [this local authentication implementation](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) (using Sequelize instead of Mongoose, but this should be DB agnostic), and here is my following directory hierarchy:

```
app.js
package.json
node_modules
config
-----env
-----config.js
-----passport.js
-----sequelize.js
views
-----index.ejs
-----login.ejs
-----signup.ejs
```

I have the routes defined in app.js and the models defined in sequelize.js, as described below:

---

### ./app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('./config/sequelize');
const config = require('./config/config');
const passport = require('passport');
const strategies = require('./config/passport')(passport);

const env = 'development';
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.listen(port);

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    else{
        res.redirect('/');
    }
}

app.post('/signup', function(req, res){
    console.log("nothing");
    passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/signup', 
        failureFlash : false // allow flash messages
    }
}));
```

---

### ./config/passport.js

```
const LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../config/sequelize');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log("Serializing user");
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        console.log("Deserializing user");
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
           usernameField : 'email',
           passwordField : 'password',
           passReqToCallback : true 
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {
            console.log("Inside local strategy");
            process.nextTick(function() {
                User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user){
                    if (err){
                       console.log("nothing");
                       return done(err);
                    }
                    if (user) {
                       console.log("There is already a user attached to this email.");
                       return done(null);
                    } 
                    else {
                       const newUser = new User();
                       newUser.local.email    = email;
                       newUser.local.password = password;
                       newUser.save(function(err) {
                           if (err)
                               throw err;
                           return done(null, newUser);
                       });
                   }
               });    
           });
      }));
};
```

---

### ./views/signup.ejs

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Node Authentication</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- load fontawesome -->
        <style> body { padding-top:80px; }</style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="container">
           <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
               <h1><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Signup</h1>
               <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
                   <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
               <% } %>

               <form action="/signup" method="post">
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                   </div>

                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Signup</button>
               </form>

               <hr>
               <p>Already have an account? <a href="/login">Login</a></p>
               <p>Or go <a href="/">home</a>.</p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And for good measure:

---

### ./config/sequelize.js

```
const path      = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const _         = require('lodash');
const config    = require('./config');
const db        = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.name, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
    host: config.db.host,
    port: config.db.port,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    storage: config.db.storage
});

sequelize
   .authenticate()
   .then(function(err) {
       console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
   }, function (err) { 
       console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
   });

const User = sequelize.define('User', {
     username: Sequelize.STRING,
     email: Sequelize.STRING,
     password: Sequelize.STRING
});

sequelize.sync();

module.exports = User;
```

What occurs when I run the app and press the signup button

[image]

is the "nothing" console.log statement in config/passport.js, but when I try to diagnose the source of the error by adding console.log statements on 'err' nothing appears to show up on cmd.

Comment: Sequelize use promises. This code is totally wrong ```User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });``` , findById ( http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findbyidid-options-promiseinstance ) returns a promise